# View all a fonts characters app?

Tags: font, internationalization, font-book

Is there a Mac app for viewing all the characters of a font?

Font book doesn't seem have this feature.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Font Book does in fact have a view that displays all glyphs provided by a font — just select *Preview - Repertoire* on the menu bar:

[image: Fontbook preview all glyphs]

You can also get a preview of a font using Quick Look: select a font file (from /Library/Fonts) and press <kbd>space</kbd>.

Answer (score 20):

I use character maps heavily and decides to make one which you access from anywhere using [a web interface](http://mathew-kurian.github.io/CharacterMap/) and requires no installation.

**Features**

- Select your own font file
- Provides font and character information
- Character copy-able
- Supports TTF/OTF
- Supports Icon fonts
- Smooth interface
- No installation necessary
- No server upload necessary

**Screenshot**

[image: Imgur]

Comment: This web interface awesome thanks for sharing with our.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're on Lion - right ?

Because in Snow-Leopard you could get that by showing the "character viewer" from the inputs menu or launching directly `/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app` as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20165/is-it-possible-to-use-the-character-map-as-a-standalone-app) and choosing "Glyph" view.

[image: character viewer]

[image: glyph view]

Check out the new smilies (now part of the Unicode standard ;) in the DejaVu font

But if you still got access to a **Snow-Leopard** installation you can copy the CharacterPalette.app from `/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app` and it will run on Lion, I would not recommend replacing the Lion version, but rather keeping the Snow-Leopard CharacterPalette as separate app - why did Apple have to make it worse in the first place ?!

As you can drag & drop glyphs from the Snow-Leopard Character Palette but not from the new Lion Font Book...

This idea was inspired by [Is it possible to use the character map as a standalone app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20165/is-it-possible-to-use-the-character-map-as-a-standalone-app)

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple broke this dialog in Lion like you said … it’s almost completely useless now.

Comment: Seems that this is no longer an option: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/298587/13220

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively in System Preferences -> International in the Input Menu tab there is an option to place a Character Palette on the menu bar that can (among other things) show you all the glyphs in a particular font, what the glyph is called and allow you to insert the character into a document or text field.

Comment: In 10.7 Lion what you suggest is no longer possible in Character Viewer.

Comment: Which annoyed my so much (!) that I copied the SnowLeopard "Character Viewer" from /System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app to my new Lion installation (not as replacement, but as separate standalone app) - and guess what: it works ! I was so happy :D - The idea was inspired by http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20165/is-it-possible-to-use-the-character-map-as-a-standalone-app

Comment: Well, crap -- I like the Character Viewer. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the Snow Leopard `/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app` no longer works in newer versions of macOS. For example, on High Sierra (10.13) it crashes immediately.

It may be that our only option are apps like [PopChar X](http://www.ergonis.com/products/popcharx/) at this point.

I don't even think I'm happy with PopChar as it doesn't seem to have as strong of a numeric tabular display and so forth and so it will be necessary to keep exploring this path for various options that may exist for native options.

Comment: So sad, i try to find the codepoints for the new Catalina SF font icons but even their own special SF Symbols app is not showing the codepoints they used for their glyphs (they are all in the private block).  Don't want to spend $40 on PopChar just to get this. Apple sucks.