# Using Powerlevel9k with oh-my-zsh showing powerlevel9k icons but showing weird character '?' for zsh icons on my Mc Book terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh

I've been using `powerlevel9k` with zsh since many years now on my Mac Book. But since few days that I bought a new Mac Book Pro `Ventura 13.3.1`, and reinstalled powerlevel9k and `oh-my-zsh` the same way I used to, it seems like something is missing.

In fact everything is working except for zsh icons, I can see my themes and set them even in my profile. I've a `.zshrc` file where my prompt is configured.

The problem is that all my `powerlevel9k` **icons** are displayed but I have functions for battery status and internet connection status and `zsh icons` set there are not showing.

Here is my `.zshrc` configuration :

```
  1 # Please only use this battery segment if you have material icons in your nerd font (or font)
  2 # Otherwise, use the font awesome one in "User Segments"
  3 # Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
  4 export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
  5 export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
  6 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
  7
  8 prompt_zsh_battery_level() {
  9   local percentage1=`pmset -g ps  |  sed -n 's/.*[[:blank:]]+*\(.*%\).*/\1/p'`
 10   local percentage=`echo "${percentage1//\%}"`
 11   local color='%F{red}'
 12   local symbol="\uf00d"
 13   pmset -g ps | grep "discharging" > /dev/null
 14   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 15     local charging="false";
 16   else
 17     local charging="true";
 18   fi
 19   if [ $percentage -le 20 ]
 20   then symbol='\uf579' ; color='%F{red}' ;
 21     #10%
 22   elif [ $percentage -gt 19 ] && [ $percentage -le 30 ]
 23   then symbol="\uf57a" ; color='%F{red}' ;
 24     #20%
 25   elif [ $percentage -gt 29 ] && [ $percentage -le 40 ]
 26   then symbol="\uf57b" ; color='%F{yellow}' ;
 27     #35%
 28   elif [ $percentage -gt 39 ] && [ $percentage -le 50 ]
 29   then symbol="\uf57c" ; color='%F{yellow}' ;
 30     #45%
 31   elif [ $percentage -gt 49 ] && [ $percentage -le 60 ]
 32   then symbol="\uf57d" ; color='%F{blue}' ;
 33     #55%
 34   elif [ $percentage -gt 59 ] && [ $percentage -le 70 ]
 35   then symbol="\uf57e" ; color='%F{blue}' ;
 36     #65%
 37   elif [ $percentage -gt 69 ] && [ $percentage -le 80 ]
 38   then symbol="\uf57f" ; color='%F{blue}' ;
 39     #75%
 40   elif [ $percentage -gt 79 ] && [ $percentage -le 90 ]
 41   then symbol="\uf580" ; color='%F{blue}' ;
 42     #85%
 43   elif [ $percentage -gt 89 ] && [ $percentage -le 99 ]
 44   then symbol="\uf581" ; color='%F{blue}' ;
 45     #85%
 46   elif [ $percentage -gt 98 ]
 47   then symbol="\uf578" ; color='%F{green}' ;
 48     #100%
 49   fi
 50   if [ $charging = "true" ];
 51   then color='%F{green}'; if [ $percentage -gt 98 ]; then symbol='\uf584'; fi
 52   fi
 53   echo -n "%{$color%}$symbol" ;
 54 }
 55
 56 zsh_internet_signal(){
 57   local color
 58   local symbol="\uf7ba"
 59   #local symbol="\uf1eb"
 60   if ifconfig en0 | grep inactive &> /dev/null; then
 61   color="%F{red}"
 62   else
 63   color="%F{green}"
 64   fi
 65   echo -n "%{$color%}$symbol "
 66 }
 67
 68 POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='nerdfont-complete'
 69 ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
 70 POWERLEVEL9K_PROMPT_ON_NEWLINE=true
 71 POWERLEVEL9K_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE=true
 72 POWERLEVEL9K_RPROMPT_ON_NEWLINE=true
 73 POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DIR_LENGTH=2
 74 POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY="truncate_beginning"
74 POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY="truncate_beginning"
 75 POWERLEVEL9K_RVM_BACKGROUND="black"
 76 POWERLEVEL9K_RVM_FOREGROUND="249"
 77 POWERLEVEL9K_RVM_VISUAL_IDENTIFIER_COLOR="red"
 78 POWERLEVEL9K_TIME_BACKGROUND="black"
 79 POWERLEVEL9K_TIME_FOREGROUND="249"
 80 POWERLEVEL9K_TIME_FORMAT="\UF43A %D{%H:%M  \UF133  %m.%d.%y}"
 81 POWERLEVEL9K_RVM_BACKGROUND="black"
 82 POWERLEVEL9K_RVM_FOREGROUND="249"
 83 POWERLEVEL9K_RVM_VISUAL_IDENTIFIER_COLOR="red"
 84 POWERLEVEL9K_STATUS_VERBOSE=false
 85 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_CLEAN_FOREGROUND='black'
 86 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_CLEAN_BACKGROUND='green'
 87 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_UNTRACKED_FOREGROUND='black'
 88 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_UNTRACKED_BACKGROUND='yellow'
 89 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_MODIFIED_FOREGROUND='white'
 90 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_MODIFIED_BACKGROUND='black'
 91 POWERLEVEL9K_COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIME_BACKGROUND='black'
 92 POWERLEVEL9K_COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIME_FOREGROUND='blue'
 93 POWERLEVEL9K_FOLDER_ICON=''
 94 POWERLEVEL9K_STATUS_OK_IN_NON_VERBOSE=true
 95 POWERLEVEL9K_STATUS_VERBOSE=false
 96 POWERLEVEL9K_COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIME_THRESHOLD=0
 97 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_UNTRACKED_ICON='\u25CF'
 98 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_UNSTAGED_ICON='\u00b1'
 99 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_INCOMING_CHANGES_ICON='\u2193'
100 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_OUTGOING_CHANGES_ICON='\u2191'
101 POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_COMMIT_ICON="\uf417"
102 POWERLEVEL9K_MULTILINE_FIRST_PROMPT_PREFIX="%F{blue}\u256D\u2500%f"
103 POWERLEVEL9K_MULTILINE_LAST_PROMPT_PREFIX="%F{blue}\u2570\uf460%f "
104 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_BATTERY_STATUS="prompt_zsh_battery_level"
105 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_BATTERY_STATUS_BACKGROUND="grey"
106 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_INTERNET_SIGNAL="zsh_internet_signal"
107 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_INTERNET_SIGNAL_BACKGROUND="grey"
108 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_CRAFTSMAN="echo -n $'\uf98c' ArchitectCraftsmanShip"
109 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_CRAFTSMAN_FOREGROUND="white"
110 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_CRAFTSMAN_BACKGROUND="darkgreen"
111 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_PROGRAMING="echo -n $'\ue606'"
112 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_PROGRAMING_FOREGROUND="black"
113 POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_PROGRAMING_BACKGROUND="white"
114 POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(context os_icon custom_internet_signal custom_battery_status_joined custom_craftsman custom_programing ssh root_indicator dir dir_writable vcs)
115 POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(command_execution_time  status  time)
116 HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"
117 DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT=true
118 #source  ~/powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme
119 source /Users/engontang/homebrew/opt/powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme
120 #source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
121 source $(dirname $(gem which colorls))/tab_complete.sh
122 alias ll='colorls -lA --sd --gs'
123 fpath=(~/zsh-completions/src $fpath)
124 autoload -U compinit && compinit
125 alias python='python3'
126 alias mk='minikube'
127 alias kctl='kubectl'
128 #bindkey -v
129 #bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
130 # AWS ACCOUNT NAME
131 function aws_account_info {
132   [ "$AWS_ACCOUNT_NAME" ] && [ "$AWS_ACCOUNT_ROLE" ] && echo "%F{blue}aws:(%f%F{red}$AWS_ACCOUNT_NAME:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ROLE%f%F{blue})%F$reset_color"
133 }
134
135 # )ofni_tnuocca_swa($ is $(aws_account_info) backwards
136 PROMPT=`echo $PROMPT | rev | sed 's/ / )ofni_tnuocca_swa($ /'| rev`
137
138 export DEBUG_ASSUME_ROLE="true" # turns on debugging
139 export ACCOUNTS_FILE="/Users/eugene.ngontang/.aws/accounts"
140 export SAML_FILE="/Users/eugene.ngontang//.aws/saml_creds"
141 export SAML_IDP_ASSERTION_URL="https://sts.compass-group.fr"
142 export SAML_IDP_REQUEST_BODY_TEMPLATE="{\"service\": \"aws\", \"email\": \"engontang@compass-group.fr\", \"password\": \"\"}"
143 export AWS_ROLE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=43200
144 export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="eu-central-1"
```

As you can see, `prompt_zsh_battery_level` and `zsh_internet_signal` are functions for battery and network status in my command line prompt. They show right status color but show question marks `?` for icons, like this:

[image: powerlevel command line prompt]

I searched everywhere, but didn't find how to fix this issue, which didn't exist in my previous Mac Book setups. I can't figure out what is missing.

Any help?

Comment: You need to use/install a font which has characters for `\uf579` etc. AFAIK the question has come up before on AD.

Comment: This is just one of the reasons I advise **against** OMZ.

Comment: @Allan in this case notOMZ's fault but copying a function that you don't fully understand prompt_zsh_battery_level - still the same basic issue - don't put things in your startup files that areyou don't fully understand unless they are pure black boc that don't depend on undocumented settings.

Comment: That’s exactly the issue @mmmmmm.  OMZ own webpage says “you may not be a dev, but you’ll feel like one.”  It’s the “player vs. playa” scenario. Only a modicum of experience (and a simple search) would tell the user a question mark like this is a missing font.

Comment: @mmmmmm and Allan, I have no issue understanding the funcions, there is notthing special there, the problem is, my fonts seem to be all installed but not showing. You can see I precised that the issue is with zsh icons, not powerlevel9k. The functions themselves can be understood and even wrote by my lil daughter, I'm just wondering why those specific font are not loaded. Also noticed that I've set a powerlevel icon ascii code for network status to test and commented it out again. 
So be assured, I don't any bash or whatever programming issue. 
Thanks

Comment: @Allan as I just said, knowing what the question mark means doesn't tell why I get it. You don't need to laught at people because you pretend they are stupid, you can mistake yourself. Guy, do really think I came here just to ask what a question mark in my prompt miss? Really?

Comment: It’s not meant to be flippant and there’s nothing funny there.  I spent (and still do) inordinate amounts of time trying to get younger IT hopefuls to forget “Unix corn” and focus on becoming a stronger sys admin or dev.

Comment: I got you, but neither I'm not a young/younger IT, nor I didn't try many way to fix the issue myself. Once again, talking about my problem, I can load and set all my fonts in my profile, but the only icons missing are the one indicated up there. And as I said in my question, I'm used to install and configure iterm with powerlevel on my mac books.

Comment: Did you verify that your terminal indeed **can** display these icons using the font you are using, for instance using an `echo` command on the command line? Perhaps the glyphs are simply not defined in the font you are using.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34241/view-all-a-fonts-characters-app) helps?